# SQOOP SQLSERVER Failed to load driver " appropriate connection manager is not being set"

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, hadoop, sqoop

I downloaded `sqljdbc4.jar`.  I'm invoking `sqoop` like so from the folder (where the jar is stored):

`sqoop list-tables --driver com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver --connect jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;user=me;password=myPassword; -libjars=./sqljdbc4.jar`

I'm getting the following warning & error:

`13/10/25 18:38:13 WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.`

```
13/10/25 18:38:13 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
13/10/25 18:38:13 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:727)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.listTables(SqlManager.java:418)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListTablesTool.run(ListTablesTool.java:49)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
```

**UPDATE**

I changed the command line to reflect the comments below, I get the same error:

`sqoop list-databases -libjars=<ABSOLUTE_PATH>/jars/sqljdbc4.jar --connect jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;user=me;password=password`

```
13/10/28 17:00:33 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:727)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.listDatabases(CatalogQueryManager.java:57)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListDatabasesTool.run(ListDatabasesTool.java:49)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
```

When I look at the listing of `sqljdbc4.jar`, I do see the class in that path... Is it possible that `libjars option` isn't doing what I think it is supposed to do?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

In vast majority of cases using parameter `--driver` is not required and even more will lead to an undesirable behaviour. I would strongly recommend dropping this argument entirely from your command line. Check out [Connectors vs Drivers](https://blogs.apache.org/sqoop/entry/connectors_and_drivers_in_the) blog post for more details.

Also in addition you are specifying a nonexistent JDBC Driver class. The correct one is:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

You can see it in the [official docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378956.aspx), whereas you are specifying

```
com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
```

Notice the different order of `jdbc` and `sqlserver` packages. This is one of the reasons why it's recommended to not use the `--driver` option at all.

Comment: Thank you @Jarek Jarcec Cecho - i removed the driver setting, I'm still getting the same issue...I'll update my question to reflect the change.

Comment: changing to this  'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'  solved my problem ...this was driving me nuts..thank you

Answer (score 3):

You need to put `sqljdbc4.jar` in `$SQOOP_HOME/lib` and also add `sqoop-1.4.4.jar` or whatever version you are using along with `sqljdbc4.jar` to `$HADOOP_HOME/lib`.

I'm using `Hadoop-2.2.0`, so i put it inside `$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib` directory, and use the following command to do the import:

`export HCAT_HOME=/home/Kuntal/BIG_DATA/hive-0.12.0/hcatalog`

(sometimes `HCatlog` of Hive needs to be `export`ed or `set`.)

`./sqoop-import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://IP\INSTANCE;port=1433;username=USERNAME;password=PASSWORD;database=DATABASE_NAME" --table TABLE_NAME --target-dir hdfs://localhost:50315/sqoop --m 1`

Sometimes you have to specify the port, otherwise default works. Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this sqoop documentation](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html#_using_generic_and_specific_arguments), generic options like `-libjars` must come **before** tool-specific options:

> Generic Hadoop command-line arguments:
>   (must preceed any tool-specific arguments)
>   ...
>   `-libjars <comma separated list of jars>`    specify comma separated jar files to include in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Rotteveel.  I tried that but no luck.  I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

Recently came across this same problem. Even though documentation says that it will pick up additional jar files. The problem is I believe propagated from Hadoop jar command line option. `-libjars` is not reliable option to set additional jar file path.
Instead, choose `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` option to setup additional jar files.

In my case, I had multiple different versions of driver JAR, but using `-libjars` was not correctly picking up file for me.

To resolve this, I specified

```sh
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/$SQOOP_HOME/<path_to_driver>.jar
```

This makes sure that correct JAR file gets loaded.